# Qualitative data analysis using data mining techniques

Tags: r, data-mining, correlation

I have 22 companies response about 22 questions/parameters in a 22x22 matrix. I applied clustering technique which gives me different groups with similarities.

- Now I would like to find correlations between parameters and companies preferences. Which technique is more suitable in R?
- Normally we build Bayesian network to find a graphical relationship between different parameters from data. As this data is very limited, how i can build Bayesian Network for it?
- Any suggestion to analyze this data.

Comment: This isn't a bad question but it's not a StackOverflow question. I would suggest to delete it from here and repost it to Data Science SE. Alternately provide a MCVE and show what you've done thusfar, precisely what statistic you want and where you're stuck and then it would be OK for SO.

Comment: Yes, I already tried at Data Science SE but there is very slow response as compared to StackOverflow.

Comment: That's true, but it's not a justification for posting an off-topic question to SO. Doing so will get your question closed and, if it happens repeatedly, your account removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at **Feature selection** and **Feature Importance** in R, it's simple,
this could lead you: http://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-with-the-caret-r-package/

Some packages are good: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FSelector/FSelector.pdf
, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/varSelRF/varSelRF.pdf

this is good SE question with good answers: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56092/feature-selection-packages-in-r-which-do-both-regression-and-classification

Comment: @Masousd Thanks for your nice suggestions and links, I would like to clear one thing more that it is a qualitative data, without labels or classes. So, I can not use supervised learning techniques.

Comment: @user986789 i know, you can cluster your data(for example use kmeans) then each of your tuple belongs to a cluster(for example cluster1,cluster2 and...), so each tuple get a label, then try these feature selection methods

Comment: Yes, now I understand. Thanks again.